# PHP - Manually Set And Then Echo $_GET Data

Tags: php, if-statement

How would I for example, take a url with some $_GET data, for example http://www.website.com/something?food=steak

How would I then output steak? My current situation is that I'm trying to use the Header function to redirect to a page where I have it so that if $_GET["duplicate"] is equal to 1, then echo this, else, echo nothing. But its not taking the $_GET data I can tell I did a var_dump($_GET);

```
<?PHP if ($_GET["duplicate"] == 1 )
    {
        echo "<h1>Username Taken!</h1>";
    }
        else
    {
        echo "";
    }
    ?>
```

The above is using the url http://something.com/register?duplicate=1

Comment: And so you know. `echo "";` might as well be nothing.

Comment: You have it in the URL ie index.php?duplicate=1 yeah?

Comment: can be more precise in your question, please add the code, in which you are debugging

Comment: I think if i understand correctly you have redirected using the header function? can you please post this code?

Comment: I have it above. Using the URL with ?duplicate=1, the if statement will not output anything, nor is var_dump outputting duplicate into the array.

Comment: @AlexP Thats what I'm trying to do, but first I figured I would try manually putting in the data just to see if it worked. That code would just be a die statement that redirects using the variable at the end ?duplicate=1

Answer (score 0):

It's just a variable, treat it like one:

```
echo $_GET['food'];
```

Comment: But for some reason when I do a var_dump of $_GET, it returns nothing.

Comment: but why did he ask then, coz he is already using $_GET['duplicate']

Comment: This may seem like a daft question, but are you sure PHP is processing the file? Try right-click => View Source. If you see the raw PHP code in there (which you wouldn't see in the browser because it looks like an HTML tag) then it's not being handled.

Comment: @Kolink It absolutely is. The site itself is based off of a PHP structure that includes the header, body pages out of a folder, and the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Everything after question mark is available in form of global array $_GET.

```
$a=$_GET["food"];
echo $a;
```

also
if url has `?food=steak&color=red;`

```
$a=$_GET["food"];
$b=$_GET["color"];
```

more than one is possible. Also search for $_POST.

Comment: May I ask what is the point of assigning one variable to another variable just to output it? If you just want to reference the variable in a more convenient way, at least use `$a = &$_GET['food']`

Comment: it was just an example. meant to show that 2 are possible for the newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I figured my issue out. I have a $_GET variable that gets the end of the page and declares it as "p" for page. I need to do the following to get it to work.

- ?p=createuser&duplicate=1